# Ошибка ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Всем привет, возникла ошибка[image: ошибка]. На сколько я понимаю  возникает исключение при попытке доступа к члену типа, значение которого равно null. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться:)

Модель из которой берутся данные

```
using ClassLibrary1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
public class OutputData
{
    public double TDut { set; get; }

    public List<Class1> NumberOfFurm { set; get; }

    public List<Class1> RashGazNaF { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> RashVodiNaF { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> Tperepad { set; get; }

    public List<Class1> KolTepla { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> FactRashDut { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> RasOtnos { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> KolUgler { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> RashPGNaKG { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> TeplosodGorn { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> TeorTGor { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> VIstDut { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> KinetW { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> ProtZoniCirk { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> ProtZoniOkisl { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> OtnoshVPGD { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> TrebZnTeor { set; get; } //2150
    public List<Class1> TeplosodPriZadZn1 { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> RashPodderz { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> TrebRashGaz { set; get; }
    public List<Class1> SFurmOchag { set; get; }


    public OutputData()
    {
        NumberOfFurm = new List<Class1>();


        RashGazNaF = new List<Class1>();
        RashVodiNaF = new List<Class1>();
        Tperepad = new List<Class1>();
        KolTepla = new List<Class1>();
        FactRashDut = new List<Class1>();
        RasOtnos = new List<Class1>();
        KolUgler = new List<Class1>();
        RashPGNaKG = new List<Class1>();
        TeplosodGorn = new List<Class1>();
        TeorTGor = new List<Class1>();
        VIstDut = new List<Class1>();
        KinetW = new List<Class1>();
        ProtZoniCirk = new List<Class1>();
        ProtZoniOkisl = new List<Class1>();
        OtnoshVPGD = new List<Class1>();
        TrebZnTeor = new List<Class1>();
        TeplosodPriZadZn1 = new List<Class1>();
        RashPodderz = new List<Class1>();
        TrebRashGaz = new List<Class1>();
        SFurmOchag = new List<Class1>();

    }
}
```

P.S. Class1- библиотека с логикой расчетов.

P.P.S. В .cshtml указана модель @model OutputData (ниже фрагмент кода (место где возникает ошибка))
[image: Фрагмент .cshtml]

Comment: Как ваш скриншот к ошибке относится?

Comment: И на будущее... Публикуйте тексты, а не скриншоты.

Comment: У вас даже в тексте ошибки пишется в каком файле и в какой строке она возникает.